# How to solve Bootstrap Navbar problem Erorr: 404

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I have a bottlepy server, local app.py and when open `http://localhost:8080/` in web browser
the server start with my little index.tpl document. I have problem to link inside Navbar menu another page called `history.tpl`
When I open `localhost:8080`  `index.tpl` start normally but click to History link lead to

> Error: 404 Not Found Sorry, the requested URL 'http://localhost:8080/history.tpl' caused an error: Not found:
>   '/history.tpl'

Here is index.tpl

```
enter code here
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="description" content="PY_Bottle_template">
<meta name="author" content="datamate">
<title>FC Bayern</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/custom.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/assets/js/custom.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
</head>
<body>

<!-- Navigation -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark static-top">
<div class="container">
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">FC Bayern</a>
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" 
aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
<span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
<ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
<li class="nav-item" id="history"> <a class="nav-link" href="history.tpl">History</a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</nav>
```

and custom.js is

```
$("history").on("click",history);
function history()
{
window.location.assign("history.tpl");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try leaving the a tag href attribute blank. So delete "history.tpl" in href. If I were you I would changed it to a button tag as well.

```
<li class="nav-item"> <button id="history" class="nav-link">History</button>
```